# Generics specialization in java

Tags: java, generics

Could anybody explain, why next code isn't compiling?
I'm creating a partially-specialized Map and Map.Entry for it:

```
public class Trie<T> implements Map<String, T> {
    private class TrieEntry<S> implements Map.Entry<String, S> {
        // stupid implementation here
    }
    // uninterested code here
}
```

Here everything is ok, but then i'm implementing entrySet() method:

```
public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, T>> entrySet() {
    Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, T>> x = new HashSet<TrieEntry<T>>();
    // some uninterested code here
}
```

Eclipse says

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from `HashSet<Trie<T>.TrieEntry<T>>` to `Set<Map.Entry<String,T>>`"

So, in my mind `TrieEntry<T>` should be unrolled to `Map.Entry<String, T>` and it accords to expression in definition.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that a `TrieEntry<T>` is a `Map.Entry<String, T>`. A `HashSet<TrieEntry<T>>` is also a `Set<TrieEntry<T>>`, but it is **not** a `Set<Map.Entry<String, T>>`.

If it were you could do this:

```
Set<TrieEntry<T>> trieSet = ...;
Set<Map.Entry<String, T>> mapSet = trieSet;
mapSet.add(mapEntry);
```

So now trieSet would now contain a `Map.Entry<String, T>`! This would break generics.

So how to solve this particular problem? Easy - use a bounded wildcard:

```
Set<? extends Map.Entry<String, T>> x = new HashSet<TrieEntry<T>>();
```

You can read `? extends Map.Entry<String, T>` as "anything which is at least a `Map.Entry<String, T>`".

---

Okay, now to your implementation problem. I actually believe, that this is **not solveable** in this way because of the current definition of the method entrySet(). It *should* return `? extends Map.Entry<String, T>`, but it *does* return `Map.Entry<String, T>`.

There is actually a [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6231312) (or feature request) for exactly this problem. Looking at the submit date and the priority, a fix can't be expected soon.

So you have two options:

1. Drop your `TrieEntry` class and try to use `Map.Entry` instead, storing information in your keys and/or values.
2. Drop the `Map` interface and let your custom `entrySet` method return `? extends Map.Entry<String, T>`.

Both solutions may not be ideal, and there may be better solutions, but this is all what I currently can tell you.

Comment: Yeah, I was little bit confused with type casting. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: why not solveable? what's wrong with just creating a `Set<Map.Entry<String, T>> x = new HashSet<Map.Entry<String, T>>();` and then just putting `TrieEntry` objects into it?

Comment: @newacct By "not solvable" I mean, that it is not possible to let `entrySet()` return `Set<TrieEntry<T>>` - of course you can return a `Set<Map.Entry<String, T>>` instead, putting `TrieEntry`s into it (see Jespers answer!), but this won't be typesafe, and this is kinda all what generics is about. For example one could inherit from `Trie` and make a subclass where `entrySet()` doesn't return `TrieEntry`s anymore - so you would need typechecks and typecasts to guarantee typesafety.

Answer (score 4):

`HashSet` ofcourse implements `Set`, but `HashSet<some subclass of X>` is not a subtype of `Set<X>`. You could do this:

```
Set<? extends Map.Entry<String, T>> x = new HashSet<TrieEntry<T>>();
```

but I suspect you'll get into trouble later on in your `entrySet` method (you can't return it from the method because it still requires you to return a `Set<Map.Entry<String, T>>`).

Another solution is to do this:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, T>> x = new HashSet<Map.Entry<String, T>>();
```

You can add `TrieEntry<T>` objects to this `Set` and also return it from `entrySet()`.

I think you can also simplify your `TrieEntry` inner class by leaving out the type parameter `S` and just use the `T` from the enclosing class:

```
class Trie<T> implements Map<String, T> {
    private class TrieEntry extends Map.Entry<String, T> {
        // ...

        @Override
        public T getValue() {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is also a good solution! Only problem being the incoming type checks and casts, which are a pain in butt.